# ADF behaviour in Web 8+

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, web8.5, ambient-data-framework

A couple of assumptions/question related to ADF in Web 8+

1. Earlier (Tridion 2013) the claim store was living in the web server's session. Since Web 8, its location is moved to the Content Service. Is it now in the session of the Tomcat (hosted by the microservice)?
2. For the methods `onRequestStart/End` and `onSessionStart`, is this the request/session of the presentation server (people hitting the website) or to/on single requests towards the Content Service (the website hitting the Content Service)?
3. What is the lifespan of the claimstore/claims? What is the max size of the claim store (for all the users)?
4. The session id is used to identify a user with his respective claim store. True or false? If true, is this related to the Session cookie which ADF produces?
5. In a load balanced scenario with multiple Content Services, if a user is routed to a different service, how does the ADF behave? Does it detect the ID of the original service but see that there is no associated claim store for the user and:

   1. creates a new one with the same ID
   2. creates a new one and assigns a new ID, is the old ID deleted in that case?
6. A variant of the previous setup: In a load balanced scenario with multiple Content Services and claim processor(s) with `onSessionStart()`, do you have to ensure that the user is sent to the same service? Is the assumption that otherwise those claims (session start) will not be set in a different claim store (of a different Content Service) correct?

Comment: Just a little constructive feedback: we should try to avoid putting a bunch of questions into a single post. It makes it harder for people to answer and also harder for other people to find the answer to an individual question that they might have in the future.

Comment: Understood and will be adhered to in the future, as for this, these questions were so heavily related to each other, I decided to write them in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference in the new version. The session data is gathered from the website and forwarded to the content service. So all of the data is from the website session, hence a lot of your questions are moot.

You do have to configure the claims forwarding correctly, so if you are having a specific problem with the claims being lost, the whitelisting and the claims forwarding configuration is where I would start.

As for the lifespan of the claims, that differs per claim and is usually set by the code that creates it. You can state that the claim should only be alive for the  duration of a request or for the entire session.

Comment: OK, that makes things easier, just a follow up question, is the session data forwarded to all the load balanced Content Services, or do I need to ensure the website uses the same Content Service during the entirety of a visitor's session for said visitor?

Comment: The claims are forwarded for each request, so no -- you do not have to ensure that visitors get the same content service each time.